# Patching RHEL 6 diskless

Tags: linux, nfs, pxe-boot

I am setting up a RHEL 6 diskless installation. It is working via PXE over nfs. However, I am concerned about patching. How do I patch the diskless image if it is just a collection of files representative of a RHEL 6 installation?

For instance, if I want to upgrade to the latest FireFox, how do I patch my diskless "image"?

How do I update the root filesystem "image" using RPMs?

Comment: How did you generate your image and does it contain a complete root filesystem or do you mount parts of the diskless clients over NFS? E.g. '/usr` or `/usr/local` or are you using something like `aufs`?

Comment: @Thomas: It contains a complete root filesystem.

Comment: Then, normally you have a root directory for you image, that you need to update. After that pack the image and reboot the servers. Or do the update live on the clients. Should be OK for most packages, besides kernel. But to keep image and live systems in sync, it would be better to update the image then reboot, or use rsync to push the update from your root directory to the clients.

Comment: @Thomas: Easy enough, guess I am just used to issuing $ rpm <rpm> but how do you that on a tarball of files? Maybe I am not being clear

Answer (score 1):

The `yum` tool can update packages from an alternate installation root.

For instance, if your root directory is at `/srv/nfs/rhel6root` then you can update the image with:

```
yum --installroot=/srv/nfs/rhel6root update
```

The `rpm` tool has a similar option.

```
rpm --root=/srv/nfs/rhel6root -q firefox
```

Comment: perfect - thank you! Mine is /mnt/raid/diskless/i386/rhel-as-4/root